# Spring messaging : Can't connect to remote rabbitmq on GCP

Tags: rabbitmq, google-cloud-platform, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

[This](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-rabbitmq/) spring guide on messaging with rabbitmq does not talk about the host port configurations. I followed the same and added these properties to application.properties to connect to rabbitmq broker installed on GCP

```
spring:
  rabbitmq:
    host: XXX.XXX.XXX.XX
    port: 5672
    username: user
    password: bitnami
    virtual-host: /
```

While running the app I am getting timeout exception while connecting to rabbitmq

```
2017-08-06 17:16:54.322 ERROR 7280 --- [    container-1] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Failed to check/redeclare auto-delete queue(s).

org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.RabbitExceptionTranslator.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitExceptionTranslator.java:62) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:367) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createConnection(CachingConnectionFactory.java:565) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:1430) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1411) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1387) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.getQueueProperties(RabbitAdmin.java:336) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.redeclareElementsIfNecessary(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1136) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1387) [spring-rabbit-1.7.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
```

Tried the following but still same error:

1. Opened up `tcp:5672` through GCP firewall configuration
2. Changed the rabbitmq config at `/opt/bitnami/rabbitmq/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config` to change the allowed ips from localhost (127.0.0.1) to 0.0.0.0

{

```
rabbit,
[{tcp_listeners, [{"0.0.0.0", 5672}, {"::", 5672}]},
{default_vhost, <<"/">>},
{default_user, <<"user">>},
{default_pass, <<"bitnami">>},
{default_permissions, [<<".*">>, <<".*">>, <<".*">>]}
```

}

What could be the problem here ?

**Update**
I have installed rabbitmq locally and everything works fine.
I doubt if the updates to config file is actually not getting reflected properly. This is how I did it.

- updated the rabbitmq.config
- rabbitmqctl stop_app
- rabbitmqctl start_app

But still I see some difference under the 'Ports and contexts' section in the UI

- localhost
  [image]
- gcp
  [image]

**Any pointers ? Or is it all looking fine and the problem is something different, like with GCP setup or something ?**

Comment: My mistake. The problem was with the firewall configuration. The GCP firewall rule had a target tag that wasn't mapped to the rabbitmq compute instance.

Otherwise the above changes are enough to make it accessible from remote machine

Comment: Grate to hear! You are good to go and answer your own question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After telnet-ing to the port and checking the port config through the GCP console I figured out that I did a mistake in setting the right tag name to the instance where I installed rabbitmq.

Please do verify that the 'target tag' mentioned in your firewall rule is indeed mapped to the vm instance where rabbitmq is installed

Otherwise the config mentioned in the question is enough to make it work from a remote client